# Must the Lechem Mishna be cut with a knife?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, challah-shabbat-bread

I've been told by a few people that *Lechem Mishnah* must be cut with a knife (as opposed to breaking off a piece with one's hand). I asked them to source it, and they're still looking.

Is there any source that *Lechem Mishnah* must be cut with a knife? Alternatively, do any sources say one may break the *Lechem Mishnah* with his hand?

This [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4601) asks **why** people are insistent to cut the bread with a knife, whereas I'm looking specifically for **sources** discussing it.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4601/9643

Comment: isn't that a duplicate?

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems like it is to me too.

Comment: @Ploni If you had posed the *related* question, (1) would you have accepted answers with sources and (2) would you have accepted answers without sources. I would answer (1) yes and (2) no and so I still think your question is a dup.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any specific halacha stating that one must use a knife to cut the bread. The general terminology, as you have found in your linked question, which has an answer citing O.C. 167 is  בציעה which means "breaking" (or "breakage"). And, you will see the term חותך which means "cutting". But there's nothing that specifically states that one must use a knife to do the job.

I have been to a number of *Chassidsih Tisch's* and I have seen rebbes do both. I think the Bobover rebbe used his hands, and someone else (can't recall which rebbe it was, offhand) sliced the challah.

But, what convinces me most that you don't need a knife is that on Pesach, you need *lechem mishneh* (well, technically during the Seder, you have 3 matzot, but that's for a different purpose.) Are you slicing the matzah with a knife? If you are, please inform us who wins - the matzah or the knife :-)

Comment: Regarding your Pesach thought, that would be solved with soft matzo. It could cut with a knife.And then you would also be able to fulfill Korech like Hillel.

Comment: @YaacovDeane technically, yes. But, two counter-points to your idea - 1) *Korech* doesn't necessarily mean "wrap", AFAIK. I may be wrong with that, so clarify that for me. 2) Unless millions of Jews have been doing it wrong for a few millennia, the fact that we are using hard matzah on Pesach, I think, is sufficient to prove my point that *Lechem Mishnah* need not be sliced with a knife.

Comment: @DanF I believe korech means wrap, and the minhag to use hard matzos is not a few millenia old. I think hard matzah though is still a good proof.

Comment: @robev You are correct. It does mean wrap and hard matza, like a cracker, is an innovation of the last 200 years or so...primarily among Askenazi Jews. It was instituted to avoid people needing to bake matza after the first Yomim Tovim. Without proper refrigeration, soft matza tends to spoil. If you look among Rishonim & early Acharonim, there is a lot of discussion about whether you can even use the crackers to fulfill Mitzvat Matza at Seder.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, not all Ashkenazi poskim say that you can use soft matzoh. I'm waiting till I can find one with an Ashkenazi hechsher, since my family's incredibly careful about kitniyot

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt  I am aware. It changes nothing concerning my comments or their veracity.